# How to access host app version from framework in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, module, xcode-workspace

I have one host app `MyApp` and one linked framework `MyFramework` in same workspace for a large `iOS` project. Let's say `MyFramework` requires to know `MyApp` release version (or current build number) for some reasons. How can I deal with this situation? Can a framework access host apps `.plist` in anyway? **or is there any better design?**

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

Accessing content of `Info.plist` is possible if you can create proper `Bundle` OR `NSBundle` object of the host application. Then you can access [`infoDictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1413477-infodictionary) property to access full content.

Now the main question is how to create the `Bundle` object of host application?
There are four initialisers of `Bundle`. I prefer to use `init?(identifier:)` since others takes class name or path from `MyApp` as parameter, these info might not be available from your `MyFramework`

[image]

So to access `MyApp`'s `Info.plist` use the following code.

```
if let hostInfoDic = Bundle(identifier: "com.company.MyApp")?.infoDictionary {
      print("CFBundleShortVersionString: \(hostInfoDic["CFBundleShortVersionString"])")
      print("CFBundleVersion: \(hostInfoDic["CFBundleVersion"])")
} else {
  // Log error
  // ... Fallback handler 
}
```

*In your framework's configuration call, you can ask for host app's bundle identifier as an additional parameter.*

#### Note:

You can not directly use `Bundle.main.infoDictionary`, since this will give you bundle info from the current executable directory which might be your framework.

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1410786-main#discussion)

> #### Discussion
>
> The main bundle lets you access the resources in the same directory as the currently running executable. For a running app, the main bundle offers access to the app’s bundle directory. For code running in a framework, the main bundle offers access to the framework’s bundle directory.